# React Dropdown Value

Tags: reactjs, api, dropdown

My intention is to get several values from API by using Dropdown component.

Here is my code examples:

```
<GridContainer>
   <GridItem xs={12} sm={2}>
      <FormLabel className={classes.labelHorizontal}>Package</FormLabel>
   </GridItem>

   <GridItem xs={12} sm={4}>
      <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.selectFormControl}>

       <InputLabel htmlFor="simple-select" className={classes.selectLabel}>
           Please Choose
       </InputLabel>

       <Select
         MenuProps={{
           className: classes.selectMenu
          }}
           classes={{
             select: classes.select
            }}
         inputProps={{
        value: state.memberLoginInformation.package,
        onChange: event => {
          const { memberLoginInformation } = state;
           setState({
            ...state,
           memberLoginInformation: {
           ...memberLoginInformation,
           package: event.target.value
            }
          });
        }
        >
         {
            packageList.data &&
            packageList.data.package.content.map(({ id, name, active, price }) => {

            if (active)
            {
               return (
                    <MenuItem
                        classes={{
                          root: classes.selectMenuItem,
                          selected: classes.selectMenuItemSelected
                        }}
                          value={id}
                    >
                          {name}
                    </MenuItem>
                );
            }
            })
        }
     </Select>
     </FormControl>
   </GridItem>
```

On my API I have something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Premium",
  "price": 100,
  "point": 100,
  "term": 2,
  "active": true,
  "supplementRenewal": null,
  "termUnit": "YEAR"
}
```

Now my goal is, how can I get the values for (name, price and point) when the component is selected.

Anyone here can help me out because Im only able to get one value.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the component? What is the api results looks like? what is your goal? maybe add a code example. this question is too vague

Answer (score 0):

you are storing the id value in the attribute 'value' using

```
value={id}
```

can you try adding another attributes and storing the values of (name, price and point), like so:

```
<MenuItem
                        classes={{
                          root: classes.selectMenuItem,
                          selected: classes.selectMenuItemSelected
                        }}
                           valueID={id}
                           valueName={name}
                           valuePrice={price}
                           valuePoint={point}
                    >
                          {name}
                    </MenuItem>
```

Comment: do I need to create that value aswell? how can I call that value?

Comment: you should have:  1. a function that handles the changes the of dropDownList    
2.give it a 'name' attribute and will be able to access its value through ```event.target.name.value```